# Converting number to string to number to delete dot

Tags: javascript

I need to remove the dot in 1.400 in order to get the integer 1400, but it return 140. How do I obtain 1400 as an integer?

```
var var2= String(1.400) ;
var2 = var2.replace(".","");
var2=parseInt(var2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem ,

```
var var2= String(1.400) ;
alert(var2); //Returns 1.4 cause it is performing Number to String conversion
```

So , Change it to  `var var2= "1.400";` or `var var2=number.toString();`

And Update the replace to

```
var2.replace(/\./g,""); // : /g means all occurrence
```

You need to escape the `.` because it has the meaning of `an arbitrary character` in a regex.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way the code you've given returns 140, since `1.400` is a number literal and gets shortened to `1.4` straight away and only then turned to string of `"1.4"`. Therefore replacing a dot and converting to int results in `14`.

It's not possible to tell JavaScript that number of `1.400` is not `1.4`. You'd have to start with a string of `"1.400"` to get what you want.

Instead of going number -> string -> number maybe you could multiply the number by a thousand, or whatever order of magnitude is required.

Answer (score 0):

Using this you will get your expected output.

```
var var2= "1.400" ;
var2 = var2.replace(".","");
var2=parseInt(var2);
```

Explanation:

```
var s1 = '2 + 2';             // creates a string primitive
var s2 = new String('2 + 2'); // creates a String object
console.log(eval(s1));        // returns the number 4
console.log(eval(s2));        // returns the string "2 + 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add single-quotes around the initial string:

```
var var2= String('1.400');
```